# How can I release Excel in vbnet visualbasic after importing excel data

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, import, visual-studio-2019

Excel is staying in memmory?

I have looked on the internet but didn't find anything.
Here is my code:

```vb
    Private Sub Buttonimport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonimport.Click
        ' Open het OpenFileDialog-component
        Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            ' Open het geselecteerde Excel-bestand
            Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim range As Excel.Range

            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName)

            ' Selecteer het eerste werkblad
            xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(1)

            ' Selecteer de gehele werkbladgegevens
            range = xlWorksheet.UsedRange

            ' Lees de gegevens uit het Excel-bestand, rij per rij
            Dim Count As String
            For i As Integer = 2 To range.Rows.Count
                ' Vul de tekstboxen met de gegevens uit het Excel-bestand
                Werk_order_nrTextBox.Text = range.Cells(i, 1).Value
                Taak_nrTextBox.Text = range.Cells(i, 2).Value
                cmbkleur.Text = range.Cells(i, 3).Value
                ComboBoxAfdeling.Text = range.Cells(i, 4).Value
                JobTextBox.Text = range.Cells(i, 4).Value
                Taak_omschrijvingTextBox.Text = range.Cells(i, 6).Value
                Interne_opmerkingenTextBox.Text = range.Cells(i, 7).Value
                Geplande_start_datumDateTimePicker.Value = range.Cells(i, 12).Value 'Start Datum
                Geplande_eind_datumDateTimePicker.Text = range.Cells(i, 13).Value 'EIND  Datum
                Plaat_nieuw_of_recupTextBox.Text = "Recup"
                Eigen_nrTextBox.Text = Eigen_nrTextBox.Text + 1
                ' Controleer de inhoud van de cel en stel de tekst van de Cmbcode-tekstbox in
                If range.Cells(i, 11).Value = "GB-BILS" Then
                    Cmbcode.Text = "gb-"
                Else
                    Cmbcode.Text = "gb+"
                End If

                ' Controleer de inhoud van de cel en stel de tekst van de Cmbcode-tekstbox in
                Dim kleur As String
                kleur = range.Cells(i, 14).Value
                Select Case kleur
                    Case "1"
                        Me.cmbkleur.Text = "1-Rood"
                    Case "2"
                        Me.cmbkleur.Text = "2-Geel"
                    Case "3"
                        Me.cmbkleur.Text = "3-Groen"
                    Case "4"
                        Me.cmbkleur.Text = "4-Blauw"
                    Case "5"
                        Me.cmbkleur.Text = "5-Revisie"
                    Case "7"
                        Me.cmbkleur.Text = "7-Turnaround"
                End Select

                Dim werkplek As String
                werkplek = range.Cells(i, 10).Value

                Select Case werkplek
                    Case "PIT"
                        Me.ComboBoxAfdeling.Text = "Cui"
                    Case "SL"
                        Me.ComboBoxAfdeling.Text = "Stoomploeg"
                    Case Else
                        Me.ComboBoxAfdeling.Text = "Onderhoud"
                End Select


                If Len(range.Cells(i, 3).Value) = 3 Then
                    CenterTextBox.Text = Mid(range.Cells(i, 3).Value, 3, 1)
                Else
                    CenterTextBox.Text = range.Cells(i, 3).Value
                End If
                Count = Count + 1
                ' Voer de Buttonappadd-functie uit
                Voegdatatoe()
                '  Buttonappadd_Click(sender, e)

            Next

            ' Sluit het Excel-bestand af en vrijg de resources
            ReleaseObject(xlApp)
            ReleaseObject(xlWorkbook)
            ReleaseObject(xlWorksheet)
            Frmopvolglijst.Refreshdatagrid()
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Er zijn {0} bonnen geïmporteerd.", Count), "Importvoltooiing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End If


Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: To start, you have to release them in the reverse order of how you created them. Excel has to be released last, because it can't be released while worksheets or workbooks exist. This is common sense. You created the application, and then the workbook, and then the worksheet, so you have to release the worksheet, and then the workbook, and then the application.

Comment: Hi it is not working. I have tried importing an Excel file, but it doesn't seem to be releasing from the Windows Task Manager even after I close it. I noticed that every time I import the file, it shows up as a separate instance in the Task Manager and when I try to open it, I receive an error message saying that the file is in use.